# Is it possible to use iOS to create shortcut icon button on a user's homescreen from my app programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

Is it possible to use iOS to create shortcut icons on a user's homescreen from my app programmatically?

I need to create a shortcut button from my iOS app on home screen.When user clicks a sos button in my application, this should create a shortcut icon on user device

[image]

As shown in below screen..Sos is shortcut icon, other than my application icon:

[image]

Is this functionality is possible in iOS (**In android it is working fine**) or will *`apple reject my application`* for this kind of functionality..

Similar functionality is done in this app:
[sample app : Contact shortcut photo icon ( iFavorite ) for Home screen](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/contact-shortcut-photo-icon/id458870823?mt=8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not create a new app icon (because that means making a new app) from another app, thus separate provisioning profiles, bundle IDs etc, which cannot be generated at run time, and it will also require approval from appStore too. So, this is not possible. It is because of the security issues

And the [reference app](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/contact-shortcut-photo-icon/id458870823?mt=8) you have given in your question, this app's description states following :

*** Notice *** 
According to Apple's official request, we are very sorry to inform you that we are unable to offer you the profile installation and shortcut app icon to support iOS7 at present.  We are also extremely sorry that we were forced by circumstance to follow Apple's official request. Please refer to the fact that similar types of apps like our format can be changed like us or deleted in the app store at any time. We ask for your understanding regarding this matter. We're going to try to provide much better service to our customer. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, but that will just create an icon for the url, so that you can access it later, it won't create for a new app

Comment: What you can tell me for this application: https://itunes.apple.com/br/app/1tapwa-whatsapp-messenger/id676836437?mt=8, this app supposed to create a shortcut no?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible to create such kind of feature in iOS.

Comment: Can you please provide me any reference links for this